# Odd permissions change when using "sudo tar" in bash

Tags: linux, tar, sudo

I'm having a problem extracting via tar using `sudo` on a different computer than where the archive was created. When I extract, not only are the files extracted not owned by root, but their owner and group is "522". This also changes the owner and group of the target folder itself to "522".

What I start with is:
`/home/otheruser/archive.tar.gz`   owner: *otheruser*, group: *otheruser*;
File created on computer1, moved to `/home/otheruser/` on computer2;

Command (from computer2):

```
sudo tar -xf /home/otheruser/archive.tar.gz -C /home/myusername/targetfolder
```

Result:
The files extracted AND `/home/myusername/targetfolder` now have "522" as owner and group. So now I need to use sudo just to view the files in a folder that should belong to me.

The target directory permissions issue goes away if I throw the --no-same-owner flag, but the files are still owned by root. Throwing the `--owner=myusername` flag too doesn't change anything. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: it's not a bash question

Comment: `their owner and group is "522". This also changes the owner and group of the target folder itself to "522".` The owner and group are the first two numbers in the `522`. Owner has read and execute, group has write, and others have write

Comment: The [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) at Stack Overflow is programming and this question seems to have very little to do with that. I think you'd get better, and more, responses in a more suitable Stack Exchange site like [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com). Please consider reading [about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) too. The short answer to your question is: TAR stores numeric UID/GIDs and when extracted as root, they are put in place to extracted files.

Comment: Thank you Sami Laine. I've been getting answers off various stack exchange sites from other people's questions for a while, but am new to asking my own, so knowing were to ask them would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the user IDs of `otheruser` on computer1 and computer2 are different (you can verify this with the `id` command) and the creating or the restoring `tar` couldn't find `otheruser` in `/etc/passwd`. As [documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_22.html#SEC40), the `--owner=` flag *does not affect extraction from archives.*

If you want the extracted files to be owned by `myusername`, just log in as `myusername` and run `tar` without `sudo`, but with option `-o`:

```
tar -oxf /home/otheruser/archive.tar.gz -C /home/myusername/targetfolder
```